# Data Flow Diagram for Classes; data flow diagram level 0, level 1; context diagrams

Tags: php, class, diagram, draw, dataflow

How can I draw a data flow diagram and a context diagram for

1. class
2. a website
   level 0, level 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the dia editor ( http://projects.gnome.org/dia/ ). Will work under windows or Linux. On some linux distros it should be available through their package management tool.

Comment: It runs fine under windows too though.

Comment: i need help with how they are made as well.

Answer (score 1):

doxygen does things like this based on your code, using graphviz which might be *nix only. maybe its time to get a vm machine going if you dont have it :)

[image: class diagram]